# Stubbing and extending a class "rspec style"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In a Rspec test, I'm creating and extending the "Queryable" class:

```
  let(:queryable) do
    class Queryable
     include FeatureQuery
    end.new
 end
```

that class doesn't exist in the app, but the FeatureQuery modules does. This code works well, but it feels ugly and hacky: is there a way to do it using a rspec double?

Comment: You don't need a double just use `Class.new` to create an anonymous class instead of the keyword.

Comment: AFAIK this will also introduce a global `Queryable` class into the global scope, so is not recommended

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this counts as "less ugly and hacky", but you can [create an anonymous class](https://dev.to/factorial/a-trick-with-ruby-anonymous-classes-11pp) to bypass giving this test class a name:

```
let(:queryable) do
  Class.new.include(FeatureQuery).new
end
```

A couple of other options you could consider are:

1. Write the tests against a real class in your application that includes `FeatureQuery`.
2. Test the `FeatureQuery` module directly, rather than some class it gets included into.

Comment: I wouldn't really think of any of the solutions as ugly or hacky when used in a situation where you're writing a gem and the module provides features for arbitrary classes (think Rolify for example).

Comment: But in normal application code you should ideally already have tests for the class that consumes the module before you even decide to extract the functionality into a module.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's better to mock this class?

`allow_any_instance_of(FeatureQuery).to receive(:foo).and_return(:bar)`